# SPARQL Endpoint over JSON

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, ontology, knowledge-graph

I am looking for some suggestions around a problem that we have,

the scenario is that users are not comfortable to convert their entire database to Triples but they are looking at something that could help them to use the current REST API they have at their end.

My question is Is there a way to expose a SPARQL endpoint over the REST API that users have without having it saved in the triple store? somewhat like Ontop that gives Virtual graph over Databases also if it is a good idea to do such a thing?

Comment: Stardog says that it supports REST data sources, but not in any trial version: https://www.stardog.com/docs/#_supported_data_sources. See also https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/2874543.2874547 and https://www.mdpi.com/2078-2489/9/12/310/htm. IMHO, it's easier to create a virtual graph over an underlying database than over an exposed REST API.